# Desctructure array returned by await Promise.all()

Tags: node.js, typescript

If I get the values returned by await Promise.all() like below:

```
const [foo, bar] = await Promise.all<Object, Object>([
    fooPromise(),
    barPromise()
]).catch(err => next(err));
```

I get the error: `Type 'void | [Object, Object]' must have a '[Symbol.iterator]()' method that returns an iterator.`

(`[foo, bar]` is flagged as error)

Comment: You can either use an `await` in a `try...catch` block, or `.then(...).catch(...)`, not both. Right now, you are awaiting `catch(...)`

Comment: please show us your actual code, `[applications, members]` does not appear in your code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you `catch` a Promise, the resulting Promise *resolves* to the value returned by the `.catch`. So, here if there's an error, the expression that `[foo, bar]` will attempt to destructure will be whatever's returned by `next(err)`, which is not what you want.

You could catch the errors *outside* of the `Promise.all` call:

```
try {
    const [foo, bar] = await Promise.all<Object, Object>([
        fooPromise(),
        barPromise()
    ]);
    // use foo and bar
} catch(err) {
    next(err);
}
```

Or, without `await`:

```
Promise.all<Object, Object>([
    fooPromise(),
    barPromise()
])
    .then(([foo, bar]) => {
        // use foo and bar
    })
    .catch(err => next(err));
```

Comment: It reinforces something I tell all my JS devs: even if it seems to work don't mix async/await with fluent methods on promises.